# What is the difference between " many a watchful nights vs many watchful nights?

Tags: grammar, usage

What is the difference between "many a watchful nights were spent watching the sky vs many watchful nights were spent watching the sky,"? How does the article a make a difference in the preceding sentence?what is the grammatical or syntactical difference between the both sentences?please elaborate.

Comment: The first one is wrong. As Michael says, it should be _many a night_ in the singular.

Answer (score 2):

**They mean the same thing.**

Expressions of the form `many a` are old-fashioned and often found in poetry, songs, florid writing, etc. 'Many a' must be followed by a **singular noun and verb**:

Many **a watchful night was spent** watching the sky.

> Many a/an...
>
> The fixed expression many a/an... is more formal than the single word
> many, and it is much less common. Many a/an... is used mainly in
> literary writing and newspapers. Like the adjective and pronoun many
> discussed above, many a/an... is used to indicate a large number of
> something. However, it takes a singular noun, which can be followed by
> a singular verb. Here are some examples:
>
> *It remained a mystery for many a year.*  [=for many years]
> *I've been
> there many a time.*  [=many times]
> *Many a politician has promised to
> make changes.* [Politician and has are singular.]

[The difference between "many" and "many a...." (Britannica.com)](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/the-difference-between-many-and-many-a#:%7E:text=The%20fixed%20expression%20many%20a,a%20large%20number%20of%20something.)

The more usual way of expressing an idea of this type is to use `many` followed by a **plural noun and verb**:

Many **watchful nights were spent** watching the sky.

Comment: Note: the very old-fashioned or archaic construction `Nary a...` is similar in structure and opposite in meaning, and 'Nary a night was spent (doing something)' means 'not one single night was spent...' or 'No nights [at all] were spent...'